# Disable the click-ability the currently selected list item of an `ExpandableListView`

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I'm trying disable the click-ability the currently selected list item of an `ExpandableListView` (to avoid reloading the same item's record), but attempting to set `view.Clickable = false;` or `view.Enabled = false;` in the `Adapter`'s `GetChildView` override doesn't seem have an effect.

The currently selected/highlighted list item (`LinearLayout`) is set with:

```
SetItemChecked(_selectedViewFlatPosition, true);
SetSelection(_selectedViewFlatPosition);
```

**ExpandListAdapter**

```
public class ExpandListAdapter : ExpandListAdapterBase
{
    public override View GetChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, bool isLastChild, View view, ViewGroup parent)
    {   
        if (view == null || view.GetType() != typeof(ListItem))
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)_context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
            view = inflater.Inflate(_._listItemLayoutId, parent, false);
        }

        int pos = _.GetFlatListPosition(GetPackedPositionForChild(groupPosition, childPosition));
        if (pos == _._selectedViewFlatPosition)
        {
            //view.Clickable = false;
            view.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            //view.Clickable = true;
            view.Enabled = true;
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I instead handled it in the `OnChildClick` listener within the `ExpandableListView`

```
public ExpandableListView(Context context, IAttributeSet attributes)
    : base(context, attributes)
{
    ChildClick += OnChildClick;
}

public void OnChildClick(object o, ChildClickEventArgs a)
{
    //ExpandableListView parent = a.Parent;
    //View view                 = a.ClickedView;
    int groupPosition           = a.GroupPosition;
    int childPosition           = a.ChildPosition;
    //long id                   = a.Id;

    // ignore re-selection (which will reload current record)
    if (groupPosition == _selectedItemGroupPosition 
        && childPosition == _selectedItemChildPosition)
    {
        return;
    }

    // or, alternatively
    if (_selectedItemFlatPosition == GetFlatListPosition(GetPackedPositionForChild(groupPosition, childPosition)))
    {
        return;
    }

    var adapter = (ExpandListAdapterX)ExpandableListAdapter;

    int childType = adapter.GetChildType(groupPosition, childPosition);

    switch ((ChildTypes)childType)
    {
        case ChildTypes.GroupButtonBar:             
            break;

        case ChildTypes.ListItem:

            _selectedViewFlatPosition = GetFlatListPosition(GetPackedPositionForChild(groupPosition, childPosition));
            SetItemChecked(_selectedViewFlatPosition, true);
            ClearSelectedListItem();

            // needs mvvm observation
            List[groupPosition].SelectedItem = List[groupPosition][childPosition - 1];
            _selectedItemGroupPosition = groupPosition;
            _selectedItemChildPosition = childPosition;

            ListItemClicked?.Invoke(this, new ListItemClickEventArgs(groupPosition));

            break;
    }
}
```